# 'likert' issue ; number of levels

Tags: r, likert

I am new to R, and i am using the "likert" package to illustrate survey data.
I have the following issue.

When i plot a likert-scale where all options are used, (the dataset contains observations for each of the 4 categories) i have no problem. But if no answers are present for one of the categories, i get the error:

*item3 <- likert(comb2)*
 **Error in likert(comb2) : 
  All items (columns) must have the same number of levels**

I see the following option for the function 'likert': **nlevels = length(levels(items[, 1])))** 
This might contain a solution, as the text says: 
                                    "number of possible levels. Only necessary if there are missing levels."

However i dont know how to fill out the option.

My data looks like this:

*str(comb2)
'data.frame':   1475 obs. of  2 variables:*

$ Jeg er god til at bruge en computer (land) : Factor w/ 4 levels "a: Meget enig",..

$ Jeg er god til at bruge en computer (skole): Factor w/ 3 levels "a: Meget enig",..

The options are:  "a: Meget enig" , "b: Lidt enig" ,  "c: Lidt uenig" , "d: Meget uenig" , 
Where one of the options are not present in one of the columns

Comment: please post sample data and the code you are using

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue, by using this command:

```
factor(var$col, levels=c(1:4), labels = c("a: Meget enig","b: Lidt enig","c: Lidt uenig", "d: Meget uenig"))
```

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3):

There is another potential reason for this error which is quite counterintuitive: The same error message is also thrown when you use a tibble instead of a dataframe!
I asked the package author to fix the error message or include the handling of tibbles - please upvote [this feature request](https://github.com/jbryer/likert/issues/11#issuecomment-630730591) on Github.

So just transform your data explicitly into a dataframe with `as.data.frame(your_data)` and try again.

Otherwise, you can follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/jbryer/likert/blob/master/demo/UnusedLevels.R) given by the package author in the case of unused factor levels.